# Error while installing Contact synchronization (ASP.NET) in tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have Set up the Synchronization Server for Contacts in ASP.net but when try to browse the ProfileSync.aspx page I am getting the error as

```
 "Configured E-mail address is not an existing extended detail field"
 "Creating a Contact object failed, while the database settings seem to be correct. Check the cd_audience_manager_conf.xml configuration file."
```

The cd_audience_manager_conf.xml configuration file settings:

```
 <ExtendedDetails>
    <!-- Name of extended details field that contains the e-mail address -->
    <EmailAddressFieldName>MAIL</EmailAddressFieldName>
    <!-- Name of extended details field(s) used for Contact identification. -->
    <!-- These are always considered mandatory fields -->
    <ContactIdentification>
        <Field>IDENTIFICATION_KEY</Field>
        <Field>IDENTIFICATION_SOURCE</Field>
    </ContactIdentification>
 </ExtendedDetails>
```

The OutboundEmail.xml settings are:

```
<ContactDetails>
<ItemTitle format="{NAME} {SURNAME} ({MAIL})" />
<ContactDetail name="IDENTIFICATION_KEY" enableSearch="false" isIdentificationKey="true">
  <Label>Identification key</Label>      
</ContactDetail>
<ContactDetail name="IDENTIFICATION_SOURCE" enableSearch="false" isIdentificationKey="true">
  <Label>Import source</Label>
</ContactDetail>
<ContactDetail name="NAME" enableSearch="true">
  <Label>First name</Label>
</ContactDetail>
<ContactDetail name="SURNAME" enableSearch="true">
  <Label>Last name</Label>
</ContactDetail>
<ContactDetail name="MAIL" enableSearch="true" isEmailAddress="true">
  <Label>xyz@cc.com</Label>
</ContactDetail>
<ContactDetail name="COMPANY" enableSearch="true">
  <Label>Company</Label> 
 </ContactDetail>
</ContactDetails>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you added/checked the corresponding 'extended detail' columns in Outbound E-mail database?

Comment: Not sure if its related but your OutboundEmail.xml is not well formed. Its missing a closing "</ContactDetail>" from the Company field.

Comment: Thanks Huston. Yes I have already checked the contact_extended_details table and it is empty. I tried adding one row but its identity_insert is off. Is it fine if I still add the required detail there?

Comment: Thanks Neil, in the question I tried copying only the relevant details of outboundemail.xml because of which I missed that closing tag. I have now edited my question.

Comment: Hi Meenakshi - Would you consider committing to the SDL Tridion Q&A proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=roT8Fgc1D1WNn9xqeeO2NA2 - It would really help us get a dedicated Stack Exchange site

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you don't have a MAIL extended detail field in your database even though your configuration file states that is the e-mail address field.

If you have a different field than MAIL that you want to use for the e-mail address of your Contacts, simply update the  section of cd_audience_manager_conf.xml.

If MAIL is the correct field to use, you probably still need to [set up your extended detail fields](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_F37955E6B98E46BF9EB08CAB2EBAC190) in your database.

(P.S. OutboundEmail.xml is not relevant in this case -- it's only used on the Content Manager machine)

Comment: I tried inserting the extended detail fields in the database(following the steps mentioned in the document) but still the same error :(

Comment: Did you restart your web application server afterwards? The information is cached...

Comment: yes but not the database server. Do I need to restart the database server also?

Comment: You also need to restart the synchronization service

Comment: Also, you might want to double-check that your database settings are actually correct. Maybe it's not connecting to the database you think it's connecting to -- or maybe someone accidentally switched the two databases around.

Answer (score 1):

For creating the database entries you can refer to [this link](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_0AB6D192D7AB4EC18892631F519EF1DD#addHistory=true&filename=ConfiguringContacts_CreatingCustomContactDetails.xml&docid=task_D3B627C67A3849FB839D1B0B4E97BEFB&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_D3B627C67A3849FB839D1B0B4E97BEFB&url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=%253CContactDetail%2520name%253D%2522MAIL%2522&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1350460433584) (Requires login).
I haven't tried this, but this seems to be a DBA task.

Comment: I tried inserting the extended detail fields in the database(following the steps mentioned in the document) but still the same error :(